# What caches uses Alfresco and how to properly clean them?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

After several experiments with business processes, I noticed that the old definitions of business processes *somewhere* is cached.

For example, I developed some business process, then installed the AMP file with it. I worked with it, and then decided to make some changes.

For this, I again assembled the AMP file and installed it:

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar uninstall some-module-repo tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
...
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar install amps/some-module-repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
...
```

But I don't see my changes after deploy! To make the change take effect I have to make quite a lot of extra work.

[Sequence of actions](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/206631-how-to-reset-alfresco-42c-community#comment-736763):

1 Shutdown Tomcat

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo ./alfresco.sh stop
```

2 Re-create the alfresco database

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo -i -u postgres
[postgres@docflow ~]$ psql
psql (9.5.5)
postgres=#
postgres=# drop database alfresco;
...
postgres=# create database alfresco;
...
postgres=# alter database alfresco owner to alfresco;
...
postgres=# \q
[postgres@docflow ~]$ exit
```

3 Remove everything from `alf_data`

```
[bykovan@docflow alf_data]$ sudo rm -r *
```

4 Remove `alfresco` and `share` folders

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo rm -r alfresco
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo rm -r share
```

5 Start Tomcat

```
[bykovan@docflow alfresco-community]$ sudo ./alfresco.sh start
```

6 Wait until the database is initialized...

7 Set the administrator's password

```
SELECT 
    anp1.node_id, // paste to the update statement
    anp1.qname_id, // paste to the update statement
    anp1.string_value 
FROM alf_node_properties anp1 
    INNER JOIN alf_qname aq1 ON aq1.id = anp1.qname_id 
    INNER JOIN alf_node_properties anp2 ON anp2.node_id = anp1.node_id 
    INNER JOIN alf_qname aq2 ON aq2.id = anp2.qname_id 

WHERE aq1.local_name = 'password'  
    AND aq2.local_name  = 'username' 
    AND anp2.string_value = 'admin';


UPDATE 
    alf_node_properties 
SET 
    string_value='209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634' 
WHERE node_id=... and qname_id=...;
```

(where `'209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634'` is NTLM-encoded string `'admin'`)

8 Restart Tomcat

9 Log-in as `Admin` with password `admin`, add users etc...

What caches uses Alfresco and how to properly clean them?

I use the following configuration:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.d (r134641-b15, Aikau 1.0.101.3, Spring Surf
>   5.2.d, Spring WebScripts 6.13, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r134428-b13) schema 10005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Axel Faust](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/16045) gave an exhaustive answer:

[What caches uses Alfresco and how to properly clean them?](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/what-caches-uses-alfresco-and-how-to-properly-clean-them/m-p/135079)

*"Any caches that Alfresco uses are emptied / cleared when Alfresco is restarted... Generally you should NEVER have to work with the database directly. It is strongly discouraged and not supported by Alfresco in any way."*

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find temp files at this location

```
<<alfresco-community>>\tomcat\temp
```

and files are stored in alf_data

```
<<alfresco-community>>\alf_data
```

Comment: https://blog.dbi-services.com/alfresco-cleanup-your-dev-environment/

please refer this link so you will get proper idea.